# Non Invocable Member in windows Form Application With Wcf Service

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, windows, wcf

I am consuming a WCF service in a Windows Forms application. My WCF service has two classes called `FulltimeEmployee` and `ParttimeEmployee`. I want to register users into Sql database by using Wcf Service with Windows Fomr Application based on employee type. The user type will come from emu type but I can not compile it and showing following errors ...

```
Non-invocable member 'EmployeeType.FullTimeEmployee' cannot be used like a method.  HalifaxWindowsFormsApplication  C:\Users\Khundokar Nirjor\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\HalifaxWindowsFormsApplication\HalifaxWindowsFormsApplication\ADDEMPLOYEE.cs    38  Active
```

as shown in the screen shot.

Here is Code for FullTime and PartTime Employee Class..

```
[DataContract]
public class FullTimeEmployee : Employee
{
    public int AnnualSalary { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class PartTimeEmployee : Employee
{
    public int HourlyPay { get; set; }
    public int HoursWorked { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the code form class..

```
 [KnownType(typeof(FullTimeEmployee))]
    [KnownType(typeof(PartTimeEmployee))]
    [DataContract(Namespace = "http://pragimtech.com/Employee")]
    public class Employee
    {
        private int _id;
        private string _name;
        private string _gender;
        private DateTime _dateOfBirth;

        [DataMember(Order = 1)]
        public int Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set { _id = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(Order = 2)]
        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(Order = 3)]
        public string Gender
        {
            get { return _gender; }
            set { _gender = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(Order = 4)]
        public DateTime DateOfBirth
        {
            get { return _dateOfBirth; }
            set { _dateOfBirth = value; }
        }

        [DataMember(Order = 5)]
        public EmployeeType Type { get; set; }
    }

    public enum EmployeeType
    {
        FullTimeEmployee = 1,
        PartTimeEmployee = 2
    }
}
```

Here is WCF service code to register employee based on type:

```
public void SaveEmployee(Employee employee)
{
    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBCS"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spSaveEmployee", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        SqlParameter parameterId = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@Id",
                    Value = employee.Id
                };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterId);

        SqlParameter parameterName = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@Name",
                    Value = employee.Name
                };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterName);

        SqlParameter parameterGender = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@Gender",
                    Value = employee.Gender
                };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterGender);

        SqlParameter parameterDateOfBirth = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@DateOfBirth",
                    Value = employee.DateOfBirth
                };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterDateOfBirth);

        SqlParameter parameterEmployeeType = new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@EmployeeType",
                    Value = employee.Type
                };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterEmployeeType);

        if (employee.GetType() == typeof(FullTimeEmployee))
        {
            SqlParameter parameterAnnualSalary = new SqlParameter
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@AnnualSalary",
                        Value = ((FullTimeEmployee)employee).AnnualSalary
                    };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterAnnualSalary);
        }
        else
        {
            SqlParameter parameterHourlyPay = new SqlParameter
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@HourlyPay",
                        Value = ((PartTimeEmployee)employee).HourlyPay,
                    };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterHourlyPay);

            SqlParameter parameterHoursWorked = new SqlParameter
                    {
                        ParameterName = "@HoursWorked",
                        Value = ((PartTimeEmployee)employee).HoursWorked
                    };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterHoursWorked);
        }

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Here is the Windows Form application code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyService.HalifaxServiceClient myservice = new MyService.HalifaxServiceClient("NetTcpBinding_IHalifaxService");

    MyService.Employee employee = null;

    if (((MyService.EmployeeType)Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.SelectedValue)) == MyService.EmployeeType.FullTimeEmployee)
    {
        employee = new MyService.FullTimeEmployee
                   {
                      Id = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text),
                      Name = txtName.Text,
                      Gender = comboBox1.Text,
                      DateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDateOfBirth.Text),
                      Type = MyService.EmployeeType.FullTimeEmployee(comboBox2.SelectedValue),//Error
                      AnnualSalary = Convert.ToInt32(txtAnnualSalary.Text),
                   };
        myservice.SaveEmployee(employee);
        label8.Text = "Employee saved";
    }
    else if (((MyService.EmployeeType)Convert.ToInt32(comboBox2.SelectedValue)) == MyService.EmployeeType.PartTimeEmployee)
    {
        employee = new MyService.PartTimeEmployee
                       {
                           Id = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text),
                           Name = txtName.Text,
                           Gender = comboBox1.Text,
                           DateOfBirth = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDateOfBirth.Text),
                           Type = MyService.EmployeeType.PartTimeEmployee(comboBox2.SelectedValue),//Error
                           HourlyPay = Convert.ToInt32(txtHourlyPay.Text),
                           HoursWorked = Convert.ToInt32(txtHoursWorked.Text),
                       };
        myservice.SaveEmployee(employee);
        label8.Text = "Employee saved";
    }
    else
    {
       label8.Text = "Please select Employee Type";
    }
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}

private void comboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox2.Text == "FullTimeEmployee")
    {
        txtHourlyPay.Visible = false;
        txtHoursWorked.Visible = false;
        label6.Visible = false;
        label7.Visible = false;
    }
    else if (comboBox2.Text == "PartTimeEmployee")
    {
        txtHourlyPay.Visible = true;
        txtHoursWorked.Visible = true;
        label6.Visible = true;
        label7.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

When I click the submit button its shows the error message

and does not insert a new employee into SQL Server database..

Here is screenshot of output:

[image: Click here to see the out put]

Please help me to correct this error ...

Comment: Any help or suggestions Will be great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to mark your enum with [DataContract] attribute and each enum value with [EnumMember] attribute like this. I also noticed that you've got your enum members as knowntypes on the Employee data contract and not the enum itself.

```
[DataContract]
public class Car
{
    [DataMember]
    public string model;
    [DataMember]
    public CarConditionEnum condition;
}

[DataContract(Name = "CarCondition")]
public enum CarConditionEnum
{
    [EnumMember]
    New,
    [EnumMember]
    Used,
    [EnumMember]
    Rental,
    Broken,
    Stolen
}
```

For more information checkout this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/enumeration-types-in-data-contracts)

**Edit:** [Here's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559(v=vs.110).aspx) what you're looking for. You should try something like:

```
Type = (MyService.EmployeeType) Enum.Parse(typeof(MyService.EmployeeType), comboBox2.SelectedText);
```

Comment: How i will use it in Windows From Application

Comment: As you know i want to insert a record nased on this enum type and combobox2 value

Comment: This is property of the FullTime and PartTime Employee................................
FullTimeEmployee.cs
namespace EmployeeService
{
    public class FullTimeEmployee : Employee
    {
        public int AnnualSalary { get; set; }
    }
}

PartTimeEmployee.cs
namespace EmployeeService
{
    public class PartTimeEmployee : Employee
    {
        public int HourlyPay { get; set; }
        public int HoursWorked { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: I do not know what to say . Can you  please ckeek it when I click the submit button still its is saying Please select the Employee type in message label

Comment: I made all the changes but still not working according my expectation